# Import OSM with osm2pgsql - missing features

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, import

My problem is missing features in `planet_osm_polygon` table. In the `planet_osm_rel` table I can find Sahara desert - it means that relation should exist, but in the `planet_osm_polygon` table I can't find Sahara at all.  In my `planet_osm_polygon` table exists hundreds of "relational" features with common `osm_is` value. For import I use command as below:

`osm2pgsql  -H myHostIP  --slim --hstore --create  --number-processes 24 --database osm --username osm  --password --style /openstreetmap-carto/default.style --extra-attributes  --flat-nodes /home/myFolder/flat_nodes/nodes.cache  /home/osm/Pobrane/planet-201109.osm.pbf`